# Any Keychain Access.app documentation?

Tags: macos, keychain

Is there any documentation about the capabilities of the Keychain Access application included with OS X 10.9?

Answer (score 1):

How about [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_%28Apple%29)? Article is pretty good.

The help many has documentation, which also is published on the web by Apple. Lastly, you can search http://apple.com/support for keychain and get several articles that document the basics and troubleshooting for Keychain Access.